# How can I get my console window to appear in a different location?

Tags: windows, powershell, console, command-prompt

When I open any console window, be it PowerShell or the Command Prompt, it always appears on the far left side of my left monitor. This is waaay too far from my eyes and where I'd like it to be. It doesn't matter if I drag it to the center or `exit` or close the window, it always reappears in the bad location.

Is there any way to get it to reliably appear where I left it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow this:-

1. Open `cmd.exe` or `Powershell.exe`
2. Right Click top frame and select `Properties`
3. In the `Layout` tab, find an option for `Window Position`
4. Uncheck `Let system position window`;
5. Enter your choice and .... smile :) .....